# Subtract 2 rows based on last previous encountered instance and column match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a very large data set (sample below) where i need to compare (column B Host, column D Game) with the last time the same column pair value was encountered (column B Host, column D Game) and subtract the date column.

Note there will be multiple instances of this pair but I need the last matched instance relative to the current row as I have sorted the data by time.

I guess I need a macro/array to loop through and find the last match to subtract. Any ideas?

I cant upload an image to show my columns because of lack of points so pasting the data in here.

[image]

```
Date        Host                            Process        Game                Status   Delay

14:22:23    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d042.sim.df    DOWN    
14:22:54    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d045.sim.df    UP  
14:22:59    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d023.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:04    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d111.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:08    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d024.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:16    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d122.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:17    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d071.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:17    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d118.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:20    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d196.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:21    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d045.sim.df    DOWN    
14:23:23    ns-mtc-gameserver-b-2.lb.df.com 172.29.101.10   game-d042.sim.df    DOWN
```

Do cell A12 -A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter this as an array formula, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and I believe it does what you want:

```
=$A2-(INDEX($A3:$A$12,MATCH(1,(($B3:$B$12=B2)*($D3:$D$12=D2)),0)))
```

EDIT:

In order to have it format as seconds you need to switch the order of the subtraction, so that you get a positive result. Excel won't format negative seconds:

```
=(INDEX($A3:$A$12,MATCH(1,(($B3:$B$12=B2)*($D3:$D$12=D2)),0)))-$A2
```

Comment: @PeterL., I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean in case data array has records for **many** servers - will your solution work as is?

Comment: @Doug, Thanks for your reply. I did a quick test on a sample with your formula and it seems to be working. Will update this thread once I have tested the sheet. ALso, is there any way to format the output as seconds? I tried Text($A2-(INDEX($A3:$A$12,MATCH(1,(($B3:$B$12=B2)*($D3:$D$12=D2)),0))),"ss") but it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @PeterL., It seems to in my limited testing. The match is based on columns B and D - Host and Game.

Comment: @Doug yeah, exactly! you "hardcoded" the values for match, but.. see my previous comment)

Comment: @user2045361 format the cell itself, NOT stored data - it's more useful and "right"

Comment: @PeterL., I don't understand what you think is hardcoded. The rows? The columns? Are you talking about the number 1 in the Match formula? Please be specific.

Comment: @DougGlancy your formula will match only value in B2, but in case I have second list of server records starting B13 - it will fail, since it's going to math other server name with B2.

Comment: @user2045361, it needs to be formatted like: `h:mm:ss` (which I assumed you had applied to column B). So right-click>Format Cells> Number and then the format above.

Comment: @PeterL., the question is to match the most recent Host in column B and Game in D, where both match. Clearly if there is no match, you'll get an #N/A. To state the obvious, the formula is relative and will match B2, C2, etc. as you drag it down. Also, obviously, you'd need to extend the formula past row 12 for real use. I'm sorry, I still don't see how this doesn't address the OP's question. Did you actually try the formula?

Comment: @Doug. Your formula works great. Took me a while as I have a slow machine. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @DougGlancy buddy sorry for the confusion, look this: http://floomby.ru/s1/GaYDq8 - I'm just wondering if it's possible to create a single formula that will handle SEVERAL servers in the array. This is just a thought, your solution is working as per OP, but I'm curious since my case is also not a rare one - perhaps for some different situations.